# Subtract a vector from a matrix (row-wise)

Tags: loops, fortran, subtraction

Suppose I have a matrix **A** in fortran which is (n,m), and a vector **B** which is (1,m). I want to subtract the vector B from all rows of A without using a loop.

As of now I have only been able to do it with a loop:

```
PROGRAM Subtract
IMPLICIT NONE

REAL, DIMENSION(250,5) :: A
INTEGER, DIMENSION(1,5) :: B
INTEGER :: i

B(1,1) = 1
B(1,2) = 2
B(1,3) = 3
B(1,4) = 4
B(1,5) = 5

CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(A)

do i=1,250
    A(i,:) = A(i,:) - B(1,:)
end do


end program
```

But this is very inefficient. E.g. in matlab one can do it in one line using the function reptmat.
Any suggestion on better way to do this?

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate of that post. I searched the forum but we used very different english terminology.

Comment: Searching is much easier when you know the answer.  But this is a point of the duplicate system: different ways of phrasing the same question pointing to a single set of answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`spread`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SPREAD.html) for this:

```
A = A - spread( B(1,:), 1, 250 )
```

Please note that Fortran is column-major, so `B(1,:)` is in general not contiguous in memory, and a temporary array is created. 
[ It is in your case since you have only one column - but still worth mentioning. ]

In the same way, looping over the first index of `A` is inefficient. 
It would probably speed things up a lot if you transposed your matrices. 
Then, a loop solution might even be faster than the one using `spread`. (But this depends on the compiler. )

Comment: Thanks. Works like charm. And thank you for the efficiency suggestion.